# Call the invalidate method from a thread

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to call the invalidate method from a thread. Basically what i want to do is to call this `onDraw` method from the `DrawThread`.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Drawing commands go here

     canvas.drawArc(oval, strt, arc, true, cPaint);
     while(i<90)
     {
     canvas.drawText(z,300,300, tPaint);

     break;
     }

class DrawThread extends Thread
{
GameView a;
Canvas canvas;
DrawThread(GameView a)
{
    this.a=a;
    start();
}

public void run()
{
    a.flag2=true;
    while(a.flag2)
    {   
        try
        {
            sleep(200);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

    if(!a.flag1)
    {
        a.x+=10;

        if(!a.flag3)
        {
            a.strt-=15;
            a.arc+=15;
        }   
        else
        {
            a.strt+=15;
            a.arc-=15;
        }

    }

    if(a.flag1)
    {
        a.x-=10;
        if(!a.flag3)
            a.arc+=15;
        if(a.flag3)
            a.arc-=15;
    }   

    if(a.x==600)
    {
        a.y+=60;
        a.flag1=true;
        a.strt=180;
        a.arc=315;  
    }

    if(a.x==30)
    {
        a.y+=60;
        a.flag1=false;
        a.strt=45;
        a.arc=315;

    }
    if(a.y>=600)
    {
        a.y=60;
    }

    if(a.strt==0 || a.arc==360)
    {
        a.flag3=true;
    }

    if(a.strt==45 || a.arc==315)
    {
        a.flag3=false;
    }
    if(a.n1==a.x&&a.n2==a.y)
    {
        a.i+=1;
        a.n1 = Math.random()*10;
        a.n2 = Math.random()*60;
    }
    a.invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `postInvalidate()` to refresh the view from a non-ui thread.

`public void invalidate ()`

Added in API level 1

Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. **This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().**

`public void postInvalidate ()`

Added in API level 1

Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop. **Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.**

This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window.

More info @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: sir how do i attach my view with a window?

Comment: view with a window? you can use `setContentView(myview) MyView myview = new MyView();` MyView is the a class then exteands `View`.

Comment: and sir if i want to add a button onto this view.how do you suggest i do that.i am a complete beginner in android.

Comment: have layout linear or relative. put a button at the bottom. add view to the layout.

Comment: sir i tried adding this view using the layout.addview method.but it is giving an error.

Comment: @user2586942 ask a new question pls. this will lead to discussion. and it cannot be answered in a comment.